# How to specify Meteor MongoDB version on local?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How would I go about specifying 3.0 as my MongoDB version when running Meteor in development? WiredTiger is installed locally and I'd like to play around with it from my Meteor apps.

`meteor help run` doesn't have a flag for it. The [Meteor repo](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#mongo-driver) indicates its supported, but not how to run it. And there was a similar question on the [Meteor forums](https://forums.meteor.com/t/mongodb-3-0-wiredtiger-storage-engine-with-meteor/2281) that wasn't answered.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why do you think you need to specify which version the db is? If you want to develop against a mongodb 3.0 server, then you could just specify MONGO_URL even in development (and it will be used), e.g., `env MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor meteor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to pass any parameters to meteor, just specify the mongodb you want to run with. This works not just in production, but in development as well, e.g.:

```
env MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor meteor
```

This will run the meteor project in the current folder, but use the mongodb running on localhost on the standard port. This works with mongodb 3.0.

Comment: Great! I guess I was overthinking the issue.